# Prove that, if $\lim_{j\rightarrow\infty}a_j= \ell$, then $\lim_{j\rightarrow\infty}m_j= \ell$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_j$ be a sequence of real numbers.  Define $$m_j=\frac{a_1+a_2+\dots +a_j}{j}$$.  Prove that, if $\lim_{j\rightarrow\infty}a_j= \ell$, then $\lim_{j\rightarrow\infty}m_j= \ell$.  Give an example to show that the converse is not true.

I have been thinking about this question a lot. I know I could rewrite this as 
$$m_j=\frac{\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j}{j}$$ But I am having a really hard time after that. Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: What have you tried, beyond just (incorrectly) changing the notation in the definition of $m_j$? You clearly need the fact that $\lim_{j\to\infty} a_j = \ell$; what have you done with it?

Comment: I could take the limit of both sides I suppose to get that $\lim m_j=\frac{l}{\lim j}$

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. The limit of $a_1 + \cdots + a_j$ as $j\to\infty$ is not $\ell$, and $\lim_{j\to\infty} j$ is infinite.

Comment: Thanks so much. I search for this before posting and couldn't find those. I am sorry to take your time...